# Can you turn a single player world to a realm server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

Can I use my single player world as a Minecraft Realms world? I have a castle map on there and want to use it with my friends.

Answer (score 22):

**Yes!** As of 1.7.10, you can upload your single player world to Minecraft Realms. The non-obvious bit is that you need to create a world in Minecraft Realms first, then overwrite it with your single-player world.

First create a worldin Minecraft Realms:

1. Load Minecraft
2. Click "Minecraft Realms"
3. Click "Create World"

Once you have a world in Minecraft Realms, here is how to overwrite it with your single-player world:

1. Load Minecraft
2. Click "Minecraft Realms"
3. Click your Realms world
4. Click "Configure"
5. Click "Reset World"
6. Click "Upload world"
7. Click the world you world you want to upload
8. Click "Upload"

Comment: Using 1.8.9, there was no "Edit World" -- the "Upload world" step is under "Reset World" instead.

Comment: In the latest version this step is no longer required, Uploading a world is now available as a first step

Answer (score 4):

Yes, with the release of [1.7.10](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.7.10) it is possible to upload your own world to your realm.

Answer (score 1):

### Can I upload my Minecraft map onto Realms?

**Yes, you can upload your own maps to realms.**

From the [FAQ](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4409253767821-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Realms-Creation-FAQ-#h_01FFK8AY97A8D6B2NESF09A6KP).