# I have a single player minecraft world on Xbox one, I would like to play it as a realm, does anyone know how to do this?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On Xbox one, I have a single player world I have put countless hours into, does anyone know how I can turn it into a realm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you turn a single player world to a realm server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162084/can-you-turn-a-single-player-world-to-a-realm-server)

Comment: That question is for java version, this is for console. The accepted answer is also based around java edition. The process for console edition is very possibly different.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that, but noticed that it wasn’t for console so I wasn’t sure it would work

Answer (score 1):

First off, to do this, you have to buy Minecraft Realms. If you have already done that, hover over the world you would like to select, and click the pencil icon next to it. Here, you should see all the options. Right next to where it says Play/create, it should say something like "Make a Realm!". Click on that and it should work.